# How can I speed up my MySQL (InnoDB) inserts?

Tags: python, mysql

I have quite a few files needing to be parsed and inserted into a table. Here's the table in question:

[image]

The file in question is 20.4MB with 81,963 lines. There are larger files (up to 40.xMB). Here's what I'm doing:

```
self.ingester.cursor.execute('''
insert into microsoft_products (bigid_sku, md5_hexdigest, content_type, locale)
values (\'{}\', \'{}\', \'{}\', \'{}\')
'''.format(BigId_Sku, md5_hexdigest, content_type, locale))
```

Here's the elapsed time from a few lines:

```
line: 6400 | elapsed time: 519.91
line: 6401 | elapsed time: 519.99
line: 6402 | elapsed time: 520.07
line: 6403 | elapsed time: 520.16
line: 6404 | elapsed time: 520.24
line: 6405 | elapsed time: 520.32
```

After commenting out the insert statement:

```
line: 6400 | elapsed time: 0.81
line: 6401 | elapsed time: 0.81
line: 6402 | elapsed time: 0.81
line: 6403 | elapsed time: 0.81
line: 6404 | elapsed time: 0.81
line: 6405 | elapsed time: 0.81
```

The control flow looks like this:

```
for file in files:
  open file
    for line in file:
      do stuff
      execute insert

commit
```

I'm very naive when it comes to database. Is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: Insert in batches. Instead of inserting one row at a time in the database, process 100 at a time.

Comment: Do you have an example of this or an article you could link me to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per suggestion by @FrankerZ you can batch insert.

When looping through the lines in the file generate your values for the batch insert.

A SQL batch insert is essentially as follows:

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES (r1c1, r1c2), (r2c1, r2c2)...
```

Where r = row and c = col.

Depending on the amount of data you are inserting in one go you may need to increase the max_allowed_packet global variable.

Database inserts are typically nice and fast so your bottleneck is that you are performing the insert for every row so +1 for @FrankerZ suggestion.